# Trignometry - Cosine Formulae

Tags: trigonometry

c = 21
b = 19
B= $65^o$

solve A with cosine formulae

$a^2+21^2-19^2=2a(21)cos65^o$

yield an simple quadratic equation in variable a

but, $\Delta=(-2(21)cos65^o)^2-4(21^2-19^2) < 0$ implies the triangle as no solution?

How to make sense of that? Why does this happen and in what situation? Please give a range, if any, thanks.

Comment: I suggest using the Sine Law instead,

Comment: yes, sine law can solve it, just curious about how this happens?

Comment: Well, the Sine Law quickly tells you the sine of $C$ is a bit over $1$.  It is only mildly surprising that the triangle is impossible, and $C$ is forced to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting your equation, we get
$$
19^2=a^2+21^2-2\cdot a\cdot21\cos(65^\circ)\tag{1}
$$
This is the Law of Cosines applied to this situation

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

where $a$ would be the distance from the $65^\circ$ angle to either intersection of the red line with the circle. However, $21\sin(65^\circ)=19.0324635277697\gt19$, so the red line does not intersect the circle, so as you surmised, there is no real solution for $a$.

Comment: thanks, i did the calculations and realized that

Answer (score 0):

Here is an investigation without directly using sine law:
From A draw a perpendicular line to BC. Let the intersection be H
BH is AB*cos(65) which is nearly 8.87
From Pythagoras law, AH is nearly 19.032
AC is 19 But we arrived at a contradiction since hypotenuse is less than another side which then immediately implies $\sin(C)>1$

Comment: thanks, ya, sine rules set limits on that also